# Collection not aware of FetchMode

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I have the following domain relationships:

```
A hasMany = [bs: B]
B belongsTo = [a:A, c:C]
C hasMany = [bs: B]
```

When I do the following query inside a `Thread.start {}` all is well (I can access the whole collection in a method called with the collection as a parameter):

```
def aList = A.withCriteria {
    fetchMode('bs', FetchMode.JOIN)
    fetchMode('bs.c', FetchMode.JOIN)
    isNotNull('property')
}
```

However, if I filter on the `bs` collection like this:

```
def aList = A.withCriteria {
    fetchMode('bs', FetchMode.JOIN)
    fetchMode('bs.c', FetchMode.JOIN)
    isNotNull('property')
    bs {
        eq('property', C.get(1))
    }
}
```

I get `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: A.bs, no session or session was closed` when trying to access `aList.bs`. Am I doing something wrong? Same SQL is generated in both cases...

Comment: Witch version of Grails are you using? In where place are you calling this query? Please give us more details about the context of the error, it really occurs when you use withCriteria, or is some moment after, when you try to access the `bs`? Also, the stacktrace will help to localize the line of the error.

Comment: Grails 2.1.1. There is a controller which calls Thread.start {} and inside this thread a service method is invoked. The query is built in this service method. The results are passed to another method in the same service which accesses `bs` of the results. That is where the error happens, upon the access of `bs`.

Comment: Why do you need this Thread.start?

Comment: Legacy code... but the idea is that the user hits a URL and that kicks off a long running process. So rather than letting page load/timeout a message is shown to the user which says 'Job Started'.